# How to create matching pattern on a pair of functions in haskell

Tags: function, haskell

I have a problem because this code below isn't working. I think it compares types, so it will always return 'a' for my functions which I want to compare. How can I fix it please? Is there any function pattern that differs functions by name?

```
leftHasPriority :: (a->b->c) -> (e->f->g) -> Char
leftHasPriority _ (^) = 'a'
leftHasPriority (^) _ = 'b'
leftHasPriority (*) _ = 'c'
leftHasPriority (div) _ = 'd'
leftHasPriority _ (*) = 'e'
leftHasPriority _ (div) = 'f'
leftHasPriority _ _ = 'g'
```

Comment: You cannot match on functions.

Comment: It doesn't compare types. The `(^)` simply gives the name `^` to the argument, it does **not** pattern match to see if the argument passed to the function is the function `^`! In the same way you can write `plus (-) (*) = (+) (-) (*)` and this is just the same as writing `plus x y = (+) x y` but using fancy names for `x` and `y`.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to compare functions? I need to decide which operator has a bigger priority.

Comment: functions can't be compared for equality in Haskell, but you can define a custom data type that represents your functions:

Comment: data MyOps = Exponential | Multiply | Divide | Add, etc.